# Combine 2 mysql-queries into one

Tags: php, mysql

I have a blog. Everytime a user comment a post they have the option "Notify me of new comments by email". But I have a little problem sending the mails to the users who have checked the checkbox to be notified.

The users should be notified everytime when the post they have commented on and checked the checkbox "Notify me..." get new comments.

The insert_comments form is sending the data to add_comment.php and i have put the code to send an email in add_comment.php

After the mysql insert comment query. I have these two queries:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS last_id FROM `comments` WHERE post_id = $post_id
SELECT id AS user_who_wants_to_get_notified, email FROM `comments` WHERE notify = 'yes' AND post_id = $post_id
```

But I don't know how to combine them into one query.

The add_comment.php looks like this:

```
<?php

include_once "blog_functions/config.php";

include_once "blog_functions/func/blog.php";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

if(isset($_POST['notify_me'])){
    $notify_me = $_POST['notify_me'];
} else {
    $notify_me = "No";
}

$time = time();
$actual_time = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $time);  

 if(!empty($name && $comment && $post_id)){

     if(isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments(post_id, name, email, comment, notify, date) VALUES('$post_id', '$name', '$email', '$comment', '$notify_me', '$actual_time')");

        $query = mysql_query("(SELECT MAX(id) AS last_id FROM `comments` WHERE post_id = $post_id) UNION (SELECT id AS user_who_wants_to_get_notified, email FROM `comments` WHERE notify = 'yes' AND post_id = $post_id)"); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        if(row['last_id'] > row['user_who_wants_to_get_notified']){

            mail($row['email'], "New comments on a post you have commented", "There has recently been commented on a post which you want to receive notifications on. \n\n The News Blog", "From: Rabeea96@hotmail.com");
        }

        header('location: blog.php?id=' . $post_id);

     } else {
         echo "There was a problem sending the email, please try again later";
     }

} else {

    header('location: blog.php');
}
```

I have these 3 tables in my database:

categories:
id, name, date

posts:
id, cat_id, title, contents, image, date_posted

comments:
id, post_id, name, email, comment, notify, date

Comment: mysqli supports multi queries http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: a few things. 1) comments should probably not have the email in it (it should come from users table on a join. 2) the max() might not be great. some type of logging table or whatnot. so in case there are 3 or 4 in there that need processed you don't skip some and go after max()

Comment: How are the two queries related ?  It doesnt look liek you are using the result of one into another.

Comment: by the looks of it so far, is most likely going to fall under *primarily opinion-based* - many ways to do this.

Comment: I have inserted the code of the add_comment.php in the description above. Im using the result of the two queries when I want to send an email to the users

Comment: thx. where is your user table. seems like it is more ad hoc without a user table. kinda like me going onto cnn and just posting a response. regardless, get away from the max() concept. you have the unique pk on comments (could even add a nullable column there like wasNotified). when you notify them, set it to 1. no need for max() which will be error prone

Comment: this could be a good use case for mysql Create Event. a scheduled event that runs every few minutes or whenever. It finds rows where they are to be notified but haven't been. sends email. sets the flag (whatever that will be) to mark them as such. no max()

Answer (score 2):

The real question is, why do you need two queries at all? If the request seeking the users who are subscribed to the email notification lives in the same request that inserts the comment, then you already have the comment id and don't need to query the database at all. You already did when you did `INSERT`. See [mysqli::$insert_id](http://php.net/mysqli.insert-id) for details.

Additionally, relying on something like `MAX(id)` is a very bad idea as there is no guarantee that it will give you the very id for which you just inserted a row. Another comment could have been posted by then, or the largest id isn't necessarily the very last one (e.g. two requests came in at the same time and the one you're looking for happens to be the penultimate).

And yes you can run multiple queries with [MySQLi::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) if you wanted to, but here you really don't want to as it doesn't serve you any benefit. You just want to get the `insert_id` from your last query and use that to find the subscribers in a separate query.

Comment: I have inserted the code of the add_comment.php in my description above. If you look at the code you will know why i need these queries

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I really I don't. All I see is code that demonstrates exactly why you don't need those queries and supports why my answer is far more effective, efficient, and ecliptic :)